# How do you handle cache busting SVG with webpack and server side rendered React?

Tags: reactjs, svg, webpack, server-side-rendering

I have a need for both inline SVG (currently handled with a sprite using `<svg><use xlinkHref="icons.svg#info" /></svg>`) and SVG used as a background in CSS (`background-image: url(/assets/svg/info.svg);`).

I want to implement hashing of filenames to help with cache busting, which works fine in the case of CSS, using the following:

```
{
  test:   /\.svg$/i,
  loader: 'file-loader',
  query: {
    name: 'svg/[name]-[sha512:hash:base64:7].[ext]',
    publicPath: PATHS.public
  }
}
```

However, I want to also be able to refer to the individual SVG icons inline, whilst ensuring that the source files have a hashed filename.

Does anybody have a foolproof approach to getting the best of both worlds?

Ultimately I want to have a source folder of SVG files which during a build are:

1. Individually have their filenames hashed
2. All compiled to a sprite which has a hashed filename and is then available for use with an `<svg>` tag?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 1):

It turns out here that the problem was fairly simple, I wasn't running the sass loader over both client and server javascript.

While I've been working this problem out I've been keeping a separate demo repository to build out a good starting place for server and client rendered React with Webpack and a good production ready set of processing for assets.

https://github.com/danielrosewarne/webpack-demo

Hope that helps!